# Scalatest with and express for type checking

Tags: scala, scalatest

I would like to test for type inclusion:

```
trait admin {}
trait manager {}

class User extends admin with manager {}
```

But I can't scalatest with below expresion:

```
new User shouldBe (a [admin] and a [manager])
```

Is there a way to apply logical expression on object checking?

scalatest version: 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trait Admin
trait Manager

class User extends Admin with Manager
```

A bit ugly with parens but this works if you want to use `and`.

```
new User should (be (an [Admin]) and be (a [Manager]))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about testing them in 2 statements?

`new User shouldBe an [admin]
new User shouldBe a [manager]`

By the way, I think it's more common for trait's name to be PascalCase